# Making a div move randomly around using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use CSS to make a red div move around randomly (by assigning random coordinates through a variable called rando).

CSS

```
<style> 

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: box;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes box {
  0%   {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
  25%  {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
  50%  {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
  75%  {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
}
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

I also tried to do something similar but with a JS function which contained the random numbers (below is a separate example):

CSS

```
<style> 
//variable is assigned here
:root {
  --rando: Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
}
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: box;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes box {
  0%   {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
  25%  {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
  50%  {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
  75%  {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left: rando px; top: rando px;}
}
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

JS

```
<script>
var rando = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
</script>
```

So far none of these examples are working (the red box does not move). I'm still new to using variables in CSS so any help or any information would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible with CSS. Random requires javascript

Comment: So there is no way to input random into CSS, even if it's through a java script variable?

Comment: you can use a preprocessor like sass

Comment: @Paulie_D if you look at the question the OP _is_ using JS.

Comment: @code but JS variables are not a replacement for CSS variables. JS can manipulate CSS but not in the way the OP tries to do it. So Paulid_D is correct, random requires JS and does not work in CSS:.

Comment: @tacoshy my point (obviously) isn't that random is possible with CSS. It's that the OP is using CSS. Look with your eyes and spot the `<script>` tag in their question.

Comment: @Jericho no not the way you intended to solve the issue. JS variables are completely different and only work within JS. CSS variables are something completely different.

Comment: @code re-read what was said. We know that there is JS but it does nothing. What we say is that you need to do randomization in JS and as such move the element randomized in JS. You can not use CSS to move an element randomized. That does not mean that we are not aware of his script but as said before it does literally nothing. It just randomly rolls a number once on script load.

Comment: You need a combination of JS and CSS. What sort of movement are you looking for eg how often roughly do you want a direction change, every random 0 to 10 seconds,  every frame, or.. and can the element ever be out of sight or is it always within the viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the root with your JavaScript and adjust the values then. You can't intermix CSS and JS.
Besides that, you need a better understanding of CSS variables. To use them you must put it inside the `var` function, as shown in the code.

```js
const root = document.querySelector(":root"); // we first get the root element
root.style.setProperty("--rando", `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1}px`); // inject the CSS with JavaScript
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: box;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes box {
  0%   {background-color:red; left: var(--rando); top: var(--rando);}
  25%  {background-color:red; left: var(--rando); top: var(--rando);}
  50%  {background-color:red; left: var(--rando); top: var(--rando);}
  75%  {background-color:red; left: var(--rando); top: var(--rando);}
  100% {background-color:red; left: var(--rando); top: var(--rando);}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Obviously this animation does absolutely nothing because you're not making the element move or change in any way, but I hope you get the point. (If you run the example few times you will realize the change of position in the red box.)

To answer the "move around randomly" part of the question, you can create multiple "rando" variables and use them:

```js
const root = document.querySelector(":root"); // we first get the root element
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  root.style.setProperty(`--rando${i}`, `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1}px`);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: box;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes box {
  0%   {background-color:red; left: var(--rando0); top: var(--rando1);}
  25%  {background-color:red; left: var(--rando2); top: var(--rando3);}
  50%  {background-color:red; left: var(--rando4); top: var(--rando5);}
  75%  {background-color:red; left: var(--rando6); top: var(--rando7);}
  100% {background-color:red; left: var(--rando8); top: var(--rando9);}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

(I've changed 20px to 200px so you can actually see the animation difference.)

For better luck on your CSS variable venture next time I highly suggest reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and [how to change them with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript).

Comment: Yea that  works, thanks for the explanation. Still got a lot of studing to do with CSS but you did put me on the right track. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this purely with CSS. You will probably need Javascript to edit the CSS. In Javascript, repeat

```
<your element>.style.top = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
<your element>.style.left = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
```

over time to randomize the position of your element. Ensure that you have `position: absolute;` set in the CSS of your element.